# Modules as morphisms to endomorphism rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

An $A$-module $M$ may be thought of as a (surjective) ring homomorphism $f: A \to E(M)$, where $E(M)$ is a ring of group endomorphisms of $M$. Then $am = f(a)(m)$.

Is there any more to this correspondence? Is there a way to frame module homomorphisms, bilinear products,... in this view?

Comment: Surjective is rarely the case.

Comment: Without losing any structure we can assume its surjective. My thought was that its necessary when considering a diagram with $E(M) \to E(N)$.

Comment: No, it's really a rare case that the ring homomorphism is surjective. Think to $A$ as a module over itself, so the ring homomorphism is the obvious injection $A\to E(A)$ and this is surjective only in very special cases. Just think to $E(\mathbb{R})$ which is much bigger than $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I wrote $E(M)$ is *a* ring of endomorphisms. Namely the image in the larger ring of all endomorphisms. It is worded a bit poorly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, but it's not that useful. Suppose you have two ring homomorphisms $f\colon A\to E(M)$ and $g\colon A\to E(N)$. Suppose you also have a group homomorphism $h\colon M\to N$ is a module.

For each $a\in A$, you have $f(a)\colon M\to M$ and $g(a)\colon N\to N$; so you can form the square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
M @>f(a)>> M \\
@VhVV @VVhV \\
N @>g(a)>> N
\end{CD}
$$
and $h$ is a module homomorphism precisely if, for every $a\in A$, the diagram commutes.

Note that there's generally no way to define a ring homomorphism $E(M)\to E(N)$ starting from a group homomorphism $h\colon M\to N$. For instance, if $M=\mathbb{Q}$ and $N=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, there is *no* ring homomorphism $E(\mathbb{Q})\to E(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, because, looking at the additive structure, $E(\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Q}$ is a divisible group, whereas $E(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is a reduced group (it has no divisible subgroups)<sup>1</sup>. So the only abelian group homomorphism $E(\mathbb{Q})\to E(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is zero.

On the other hand both groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

You can't even go the other way around: consider the canonical injection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$: there is no ring homomorphism $E(\mathbb{Q})\to E(\mathbb{Z})$.

---

<sup>1</sup> The ring $E(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is the product for $p$ running through all primes of the rings of $p$-adic integers, which are known to be reduced groups.

Comment: Thank you for the post. Before I begin thinking about it more I wanted to say that the reason I looked into it to begin with was because I was looking for a more 'natural' way to define the universal property for tensor products of modules, i.e. without using n-linear mappings. I am not totally pleased with the standard formulation because it does not strictly use modules and module homomorphisms, unlike the case in the category of rings, where it's just the coproduct.

Comment: @basket In my opinion, but I may be biased by my background in noncommutative rings, you better understand tensor product of modules starting from noncommutative rings: define $M\otimes_RN$ for $M$ a right $R$-module and $N$ a left $R$-module. You don't have a structure of $R$-module on the tensor product, generally.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general question and can not be answered in a few words. So, may be let me describe one aspect. If $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ an $R$-module, giving an $R$-algebra homomorphism $A\to \operatorname{End}_R M$, where $A$ is an $R$-algebra makes $M$ into an $A$-module. In the example you write above, $R=\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, let me look at a special case, where $R$ is a field and $A$ is finite dimensional commutative $R$-algebra. Then, we have natural perfect pairing $A\times \operatorname{Hom}_R(A,R)\to R$. But, easy to see that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(A,R)=\omega_A$ has a natural $A$-module structure using the above. Then, a whole lot of duality can be worked out using $\omega_A$ for $A$-modules, imitating what happens for vector spaces over $R$. It is very powerful, as duality is for vector spaces.